# Definition question: What is the domain of a polynomial in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[X]$? Or, more generally, of $f \in K[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have the field of rational functions $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ and the ring of polynomials in one variable over this field $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[X]$.

Just to clarify, is it true that the domain any polynomial in this polynomial ring is the field $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$? Or more broadly that $K$ is the domain of $K[X]$?

Comment: You should be able to evaluate such a polynomial on any ring $R$ together with a homomorphism $\mathbb F_3(t) \to R$, or in the general case $K\to R$. Basically on any $K$-algebra.

Comment: A polynomial, *per se*,  has no domain. Only polynomial functions have and it's up to you to define its domain. The only constraint is it has to be a $K$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a commutative ring $R$, you can certainly substitute any $r\in R$ in for $X$ in a polynomial from $R[X]$. So in a sense, yes, you could consider $R$ to be in the "domain of a polynomial (considered as a function)" in $R[X]$.

On the other hand, we usually *do not* think of elements of $R[X]$ as functions, because two different polynomials can yield the same function.

For example, $F_2[x]$, the polynomials $x+1$ and $x^2+1$ make the same function $F_2\to F_2$.